# AppConfig Secrets File

Tags: c#, xml

I have a AppConfig.cs class that i am calling the different values stored in my App.config and AppSettingsSecrets.config file, however when i call the the API key stored in the AppSettingsSecrets.config files i get null, once move it to the App.config i am able to get the value.
Below is a snipped of how the set up is so far, if anyone is able to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciate it.

AppConfig.cs

```
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static int IntervalMinutes => int.Parse(Config("IntervalMinutes"));
    public static string DB_ConnString => Config("DB_ConnString");
    public static string BaseUrl => Config("BaseUrl");
    public static string DriversUri => Config("DriversUri");
    public static string DriverScoreUri => Config("DriverScoreUri");
    public static string ApiToken => Config("BearerToken");
    private static string Config(string arg)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[arg];
    }
}
```

App.config file

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="AppSettingsSecrets.config">
        <add key="IntervalMinute" value="10" />
        <add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="https://api.website.com" />
        <add key="DriversUri" value="/fleet/drivers" />
        <add key="DriverScoreUri" value="/v1/fleet/drivers/" />
        <!--add key="BearerToken" value="api_key_is_located_here"/-->
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

AppSettingsSecrets.config

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="BearerToken" value="api_key_is_located_here"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I put the api key straight in the App.config file and i was able to get a 200 code. Once i move it to the AppSettingsSecrets.config file i get a null

Comment: You are using a two step authentication where each session requires a new token.  A token has an expiration time and will only be valid for a short period of time.